# Proper way to handle custom submit button at django custom model admin add page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add an extra button at `submit_line.html` that does exactly the same thing as submit but it sets certain field to something else while sending post request to server.

Say I have a blog as model, I want to add "save as draft" as button.

My `submit_line.html` looks like this:

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}

{% if show_save_as_draft %}<input type="submit" value="save_as_draft" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}


{% if show_delete_link %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
</div>
```

Now I don't understand how it is making this request, so I can't modify it, so please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, give your button a unique `name`:

```
{% if show_save_as_draft %}
    <input type="submit" 
           value="{% trans 'Save as draft' %}" 
           class="default" 
           name="_save_as_draft" />
{% endif %}
```

Then, in your [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) you can override the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if '_save_as_draft' in request.POST.keys():
            # Do your custom stuff, e.g.
            obj.is_draft = True

        # Let Django do its defaults.
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

One important thing is that `save_model()` **has to save the instance**. This means if the method or one of its `if/else` branches doesn't call `super` you need to make sure to call `obj.save()` somewhere.

There are many more possibilities to customize the workflow based on what button has been clicked. The gist is that this information is available in the `request` instance, which is accessible in most related `ModelAdmin` methods.

E.g. another interesting use case is redirecting the user to somewhere else after hitting the *Save as draft* button, which is possible by overriding [`response_add()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) and [`response_change()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change).

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to return template after saving as a draft? So it could work like a preview feature for me.

Comment: This made my day. Thank You very much.